# Google autocomplete component requires refresh to load correctly Vuejs

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, google-api

I made a component with an input which loads the google autocomplete (InputPlace.vue) and I'm using it in two views: home and search.

First time I load the web, it works correctly, I use the component from the Home view to choose a location and redirect to the Search view. After that, I try to use it again, now from the Search view but it doesn't show the locations. So, I need to F5 to make it work again.

After that, if I go back to Home view and try to use the component again it doesn't work. As before, I need to F5.

This is my component (InputPlace.vue):

```
<template>
  <label class="form-label-place" for="city">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputPlace" name="city" placeholder="Ingresa tu ciudad">
  </label>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'input-place',
  mounted() {
      // Google autocomplete
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', () => {
        var options = {
          types: ['(cities)'],
          componentRestrictions: {country: "PE"}
        };
        var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('inputPlace'), options);
        google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', () => {
          this.$parent.placeChanged(places)
        });
      });
  }
}
</script>
```

And this is how I load the library in the index.html before closing the body (already tried adding it into the head)

```
<script async refer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&libraries=places&sensor=false&language=es&region=PE"></script>
```

Comment: I guess, The problem is that you're binding `document.getElementById('inputPlace')` inside Vue. Instead `this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      (this.$refs.autocomplete),
      options
    );`  in JS and Inside HTML add `ref="autocomplete" ` to your input and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It most likely occurs since page is not get reloaded when the user navigates to the `/search` route. Hence `onload` event doesn't fire and `Autocomplete` control is not getting initialized:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', () => {  //<- not triggered
    //..
})
```

I would say utilizing window `load` event is redundant here since `Autocomplete` control could be initialized in [`mounted()` method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted):

```
<template>
  <label class="form-label-place" for="city">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputPlace" name="city" placeholder="Search..">
  </label>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  /* global google */

  name: "input-place",
  mounted() {
    const options = {
      types: ["(cities)"]
    };
    const places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      document.getElementById("inputPlace"),
      options
    );
    google.maps.event.addListener(places, "place_changed", () => {
      //...
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

[The following demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/qxlx9kqjnj) demonstrates how to load Google Maps API and initialize [Place Autocomplete component](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)  in Vue (with [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/)) application